# Is there a way to run pip inside a virtual environment from a python script?

Tags: python-3.x

```
python_bin = 'venv\Scripts\python.exe'
subprocess.run([python_bin, 'pip', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])
```

This is what I am trying to do but it doesn't recognize pip

Comment: Did you enable virtualenv before running this command?

Comment: It's better to have `python_bin = sys.executable`.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the -m:

```py
subprocess.run([python_bin, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])
```